# Why axios is sending null data to my POST route?

Tags: node.js, api, http, post, axios

Im trying to send a POST request via a form in an EJS file. When the form is submitted the data is posted to my http://localhost:4000/getFormData (which is my client) and then Im trying to POST that data to my http://localhost:3000/user_create which is my API.

**Im using axios to send a POST request like this:**

```
app.post("/getFormData",function(req,res){
console.log("POST route of 4000 is hit");
var firstName=req.body.create_first_name;
var lastName=req.body.create_last_name;

console.log(typeof firstName); 
console.log(typeof lastName);

axios.post('http://localhost:3000/user_create', 
{create_first_name: req.body.create_last_name,lastName: req.body.create_last_name},
{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
 .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.config);
    res.redirect("/getUsers");
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
 });
});
```

**My API (localhost:3000) is serving the post request like this:**

```
app.post("/user_create",function(req,res){
const firstName=req.body.create_first_name;
const lastName=req.body.create_last_name;


console.log("Type: "+typeof firstName + " Data :"+firstName);
console.log("Type: "+typeof lastName + " Data :"+lastName);

const query="INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES (?,?)"
mysqlConnection.query(query,[firstName,lastName],(err, results, fields) => {
    if (err){
        console.log("Failed to insert new user "+err);
        res.sendStatus(500)
        return 
    }
    console.log("Inserted into"+results.insertId);
    res.sendStatus(200)
   })  });
```

**This is the response Im getting after making the POST request from axios:**
[image]

**My form looks like this:**

```
    <form action="/getFormData" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="create_first_name" id="" placeholder="First name">
        <input type="text" name="create_last_name" id="" placeholder="Last name">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: `axios.post('http://localhost:3000/user_create', {'create_first_name': firstName, 'create_last_name': lastName })`

Comment: Nope! still not working